# Binary Tree / Recursion (Java) (Update)

Tags: java, recursion, tree

(Update)

My class has been working on using recursion to create things like the Towers of Hanoi, Fibonacci, and all that fun stuff.  The problem is, I don't really understand everything very well.  I understand the general concept of recursion, but putting it into practice when making a program feels so complicated to me.  I get that it's calling the method over and over typically under it reaches a base case where it exits, but it's hard for me to write code that does what I want it to do.

We are working on binary trees right now.  We are supposed to use some code provided by my professor to split up a tree, then write a recursive method to print out all the paths that the tree contains.  Our input will be something like `(a(b()())(c()()))` which would be a tree of:

```
 a
b c
```

b and c would have 0 children below them.  `(a)` is a possible node, and `()` would be an empty node which would be the end of that path.  Our goal is to print out all the paths, so for my example, the output would be:

```
a b

a c
```

The code we are given includes a helper method that we can use to write our recursive method:

```
public class BinaryTree {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String tree = scan.nextLine();//correct format : (a()())
    String[] t = splitTree(tree);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));

}
public static String[] splitTree(String tree)
{
    //expected format
    //(node tree tree)
    //0 1 2-x x-(length-2) length-1
    if(tree.length() <= 2)//tree not long enough to process
        return new String[]{tree};

    String[] temp = new String[3];
    temp[0] = "" + tree.charAt(1);//grab tree node
    tree = tree.substring(2, tree.length()-1);//remove node and outer paren
    int parenCount = 0;//count of open paren
    int endTreeOne = 0;//end of first tree
    for(int i = 0; i < tree.length(); i++)
    {
        if(tree.charAt(i) == '(')
            parenCount++;
        if(tree.charAt(i) == ')')
            parenCount--;
        if(parenCount == 0)
        {
            endTreeOne = i;
            break;//ends for loop early
        }
    }
    temp[1] = tree.substring(0, endTreeOne+1);//left tree
    temp[2] = tree.substring(endTreeOne+1);//right tree
    return temp;
}
```

This method basically converts a string of characters like `(a(b()())(c()()))` and makes them `[a, (b()()), (c()())]`.  Splitting the tree up basically.

I'm just really not sure how to proceed from here to write my recursive method.  I feel pretty lost honestly (and frustrated as a result).  I think I need to make my method check for if "()" exists, then that is the end of a path.  Would that be my base case to exit out of the loop I'd need?  I'm not sure how to specify which side of the tree to take as well.  If someone can provide any help, tips, or get me on the right train of thought for tackling this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

So far, I really just have (in addition to the helper method provided above):

```
static ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
public static String treePaths(String s)
{

        String[] split = splitTree(s);
        if(split[1].equals("()") && split[2].equals("()"))
        {
            path.add(split[0].toString());
            System.out.println(path.toString());
            return split[0];
        }
        else
        {
            String s2 = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < split.length-1; i++)
                {
                s2 = split[i].toString();
                }
                path.add(split[0].toString());
                return treePaths(s2);

        }
```

for my recursive method and I'm pretty sure it's wrong already.  If anyone can provide any help (especially using the code provided by my professor), I'd be very grateful (even if it's just pointing me in the right direction or helping me understand better what I need to do.  Someone helped me before on here, but I'm not sure if it was done the way I needed to do it.

Comment: I think we are supposed to use an arraylist to store the paths as well.  Hmm..

Answer (score 1):

you are close. the hint for your exit condition is given in the beginning of the helper method. if the length of its input is 2 charactes or less, it returns a 1-size array containing the input. it so happens, that an empty node would trigger this if statement.

Comment: So sorry, but I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.  Should the exit condition for my recursive method (treePaths) be about the length of the input and less so what the input actually is?  edit:  hm, I guess it should because the splitTree method I'm given splits up the input into something like [a, (b()()), (c()())] (an array of those 3 strings)

Answer (score 1):

ok, I am writing a new answer since the last one isn't correct.
I have solved the problem (at least the original one that involved printing the paths only).

you are right that you should start with the exit condition of the recursive method.
what is the exit condition? it should be when you reach an end of one path. then you exit and go up the stack of method calls.
looking at the example solution you provided, a path end comes at an element that has two empty elements as children, like elements b and c in the example.
the helper method gives you a distinct output when you give it "an element that has two empty elements"

**Continue Apr 5th:**
The exit condition is

```
if (split[1].equals("()") && split[2].equals("()"))
```

in this case you have an end-of-path and the path is held by the recursive method stack.
For example: for path `a b c`
first call to `treePaths()` encountered `a` and called 2nd `treePaths()` which encountered `b` and it called 3rd `treePaths()` which encountered `c` and identified it as end-of-path.
now what is needed to make this scenario happen? how does this shape the input passed to each method?

Comment: It should really exit once the helper method returns node()() because that implies it is at the end of the path.  Like for example b()(). Otherwise, it should keep going, right?  This is all still a little confusing to me, lol. :(

Comment: yes you got it right. by the way, be careful as you wrote `split[i] == "()"` while you should have used equals.   so what is the exit condition? how does the "if" look like?

Comment: do you have an answer?? I thought you wanted to do it in steps?  or did you solve it all already?

Comment: Sorry, I had to take care of something outside and have been working on it now.  I'm over-complicating the way to do the if statement, I think.  I'm trying to remove the node letter so all that would be left would be the ()() part.

Comment: (dang it, can't get the formatting right. i'm removing the node letter so all that is left should be a string of (()()) for base case.

This is what I have so far, but it looks SO much more complicated (and probably wrong) than it should have been:

         public static String[] treePaths(String s)



 {

  String[] split = splitTree(s);

     
  for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)

  {

   String test = split[i].toString();
   StringBuilder removenode = new StringBuilder(test);
   removenode.deleteCharAt(1);
   if(test.equals("(()())")) //base case
  {
   return split;
  }
  else
  {
  }

Comment: I edited it back into the first post I made so the formatting is better.

Comment: no. this is not what I meant. take an element that is at the end of a path like `(b()())` and pass this to the helper method.  what do you get?

Comment: When I pass (b()()) to the helper method, it returns [b, (), ()]

Comment: for the sake of moving forward, I will spell it out for you `if (split[1].equals("()") && split[2].equals("()")) {`

Comment: Ooooh, okay, that is a lot easier to read/do than what I was attempting, lol.    So that would be my base case that exits everything, right?  I'm not sure what I would return in that if statement, though.  I'd just need to return the root of those children I think?  so split[0] or no?

Comment: This is really the part of recursive methods that I don't fully understand.  Like how to set up a logical path where it keeps calling the same method over and over until it reaches the base case.  For simple recursive methods like a "sum" one, it's not too terribly hard to follow.  But when I'm needing to pass through array entries, it's a bit harder for me to grasp. :(

Comment: for path `a b c`, the recursive call starts with `a b c` then it "holds" the start of the path `a` and calls itself with the rest that is `b c`.  when it sees this it does the same ("holds" the start of the path `b` and calls itself with the rest)  the rest is now `c` with two empty nodes. that is actually speling out the solution

Comment: So.. little progress in that my program doesn't give errors now when I call the treePaths method, but the output isn't what I need exactly.  and I know I'm not really implementing the return right...  But I have:       public static String[] treePaths(String s)
 {
      String[] split = splitTree(s);
   if(split[1].equals("()") && split[2].equals("()"))
   {
    return split;
   }
   else
   {
    String s2 = split[1].toString();
    return treePaths(s2);
   }

Comment: Edited the original post to make it more readable.  The output I get when I run it is:     (a(b()())())  (new line)
[a, (b()()), ()]  (new line)
[Ljava.lang.String;@33909752
I think my return on the base case needs to be different to return the path I need.

Comment: there are two problems with your solution: 1) what do you do with split[0] that you suppose to "hold" ? at some point you are suppose to build the complete path with it and 2) you call treePaths for one branch split[1] what about the 2nd branch?

Comment: 1) We are supposed to insert the path into an ArrayList, so I need to put split[0] into that each time, I think?  and 2)  Do I need to do a for loop to cycle through each branch?  or some other loop type?

Comment: you basically have the solution as an algorithm . you just need to code it and debug. now go forth and code!

Comment: I'm okay at putting what I need to do into words/thoughts, but translating that into code is the tricky part for me, lol.  Working on it though.

Comment: your firend is the debugger or System.out.println (sometimes its better at showing the whole recursion stack) you will probably have lots of trial and error but that is the best way to learn

Comment: You've already been a lot of help, but could I have another tip?  My output is getting closer, but it's still not doing it exactly right.  I'm getting duplicate entries in the paths for some reason.  Like if I input (a(b(c()()))(d()())), my output is [a, a, b, b, c]. That only does one side too for some reason - it completely ignores the d.  I updated my code in the OP.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the duplicate entries (moved the path.add(split[0].toString()); outside of the for loop), but I'm still not able to print out the path of the other side.. Hmm.

Comment: Oh interesting.. when i changed my for loop to be when i < split.length (instead of length-1), it printed out the OTHER path (a, d) but NOT (a, b, c)... bizarre...  I feel like Im so close.

Comment: On something far longer like (a(b(p(m()())(n()()))())(b(c()())(a(b(a()())())(a()())))) , it only does the first path too:  [a, b, p, m]   :(  If I change the for loop to length (not length-1), it does the other path (a, b, a, a), but none of the others.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because of something wrong with my for loop.  Like I'm only making s2 go up and up until it reaches the last one then putting that back into treePaths.  Wouldn't i need to run treePaths on every version of s2?